# Android 4.0 development - onMenuItemSelected(int,Menu)

Tags: android

I ve just upgraded my Android  application from api level 13 to 14, using simulator 4.0.

Can anyone  that is using level 14 api confirm that there is a problem with

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)
{
switch(item.getItemId())
           {
                case android.R.id.home:
...
}
```

function ? If i compile with level 13 api, i can click on the main activity icon ( left up) and i go to this method in r.id.home case, but with upgrading to api level 14 that function is not called and it looks like the icon is not clickable :(

I am just wondering if it is a bug in this just newly released api..

Answer (score 5):

From the Action Bar documentation:

> Note: If you're using the icon to navigate to the home activity,
>   beware that beginning with Android 4.0 (API level 14), you must
>   explicitly enable the icon as an action item by calling
>   setHomeButtonEnabled(true) (in previous versions, the icon was enabled
>   as an action item by default).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the overload you're using for onOptionsItemSelected. The Android reference shows that the only overload is onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) and the following is definitely working for me:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
```

Comment: do you have the latest emulator, 4.0 platform api 14? i know what the references says..

Comment: I ve migrated back to 3.2 and the same problem went away, default icon up left is clickable and the function i mentioned up is called.. bdw i didnt migrate cause of the icon but because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200865/android-emulator-platform-4-0-startup-problems