# Android emulator platform 4.0 startup problems

Tags: android, emulation

i ve just migrated to Ice cream sandwich emulator 4.0, and i have many difficulties startign it up..

Sometimes i get database connection existed error, and wont start, then something like thread 52 violation, now the emulator loaded but when i tried to unlocked it i got some policyviolation error and it frozed.

I am really frustrated, anyone else has the same problems ? If so , were they fixed, and how, otherwise i see no other way but migrating back to 3.2 ...

Bdw i am using ubuntu 11.04

Thanks

Edit: I ve migrated back to 3.2 because after 1 hour i still couldnt start it. Yesterday i ve managed to work on 4.0 for a little while after my load was successful after tryying to load it for quite some time, but to no avail today.. I got reminded why i dont jump on next ubuntu release right after its out :) Bdw.. question still stands, so we can maybe fix a problem of anyone else having the same problem..

tnx

Comment: very ironic! Ive been having issues getting my code that works fine in 2.1 to work in 4.0, infact it just crashes everytime I try to run it, if im just making a simple view it works fine but once you start throwing in and webviews, oauth authentication etc it wont work not sure whats up here tbh

Comment: Well my code from 3.2 works just fine on 4.0 emulator, but i had a really HARD time starting it up so i gave up for now :)

Comment: ya I think I will too for now until they get this sorted out lol its really wasting my precious time at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem I also faced.. But this may be 4.0 SDK is is not so stable yet.

I was trying to use both Emulator and One Target connected to Eclips.

I facing same problem repeatedly. So I disconnected one and after that it worked fine.

One target at a time worked well.